# Is it possible to get overview of a CTE?

Tags: sql, oracle

In sql developer I can do

```
desc table
```

and get

```
describe table
Name                   Null Type          
---------------------- ---- ------------- 
DATE_TIME                    DATE          
KEY                          VARCHAR2(11)
```

Is something like this possible with a CTE? For example if there are 10 columns in table, I will get the description of all of them. But what if I want the description of only 2 columns.

```
with alias as (select col1, col2 from table) desc alias
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a trick:

```
CREATE VIEW dummy AS
WITH ..
SELECT ..
```

And then:

```
DESC dummy
```

Comment: This works because `DESC` works with tables _and_ views.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes. Nifty, eh?

Comment: I was literally a minute away from posting and I saw you come in first, hence +1 to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.

A CTE is not stored anywhere in the system catalogs. It's essentially the same as a derived table:

```
with alias as (select col1, col2 from table) 
select * from alias
```

is the same as

```
select * 
from ( select col1, col2 from table) alias
```

And you can't `describe` that derived table either.

The only way you can do something remotely similar is to select from the CTE but with a `where` condition that selects not rows.

```
with alias as (select col1, col2 from table) 
select * from alias
where 0 = 42;
```

Then you would at least see the column names and data types (the details of that depend on the SQL client you are using)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without creating a view, with something a bit more complicated:

```
create table yourTable(
DATE_TIME                    DATE,          
KEY                          VARCHAR2(11)
);
```

You can use [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_SQL.htm#ARPLS058) to describe the columns of a `select` query:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_Cursor        INTEGER DEFAULT dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  3    l_Stmt          VARCHAR2(4000);
  4    l_colCnt        NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
  5    l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  6  BEGIN
  7    dbms_sql.parse(l_Cursor, 'SELECT key FROM yourTable', dbms_sql.native);
  8    dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_Cursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl);
  9    --
 10    FOR i IN 1..l_colCnt LOOP
 11        dbms_output.put_line('Column '||l_descTbl(i).col_name || ' - type '||l_descTbl(i).col_type);
 12    END LOOP;
 13    --
 14    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_Cursor);
 15  END;
 16  /
Column KEY - type 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The result must be interpreted by this table:

```
Datatype    Number
VARCHAR2    1
NVARCHAR2   1
NUMBER      2
INTEGER     2
LONG        8
ROWID       11
DATE        12
RAW         23
LONG RAW    24
CHAR        96
NCHAR       96
MLSLABEL    106
```

So, it is saying that the column `KEY` has type `1`, that is a `VARCHAR2`    .
The same way you can have more informations, about size for example.